# $(document) inside iframe does not work properly for injected scripts

Tags: jquery

I have a iframe. when I load the iframe in a normal way, all the `$(document)` refer to the iframe document.

But when I inject some script from the main window into the iframe body, `$(document)` refers to the main document and not the iframe.

**I need that injected `$(document)` refers to the iframe document and not to the main document.**

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/methmad9/5/

You can see in the console that injected  `$(document)` show the same content as the `$(document)`

Comment: use `$('#myIframe').contents()` for not cross domain iframe

Comment: @A.Wolff I can not, because the injected code can be also loaded inside another element other than an iframe

Comment: Post relevant code regarding script injection. I guess issue is because jQuery using internally `$.globalEval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from jQuery using `$.globalEval`:

> This method behaves differently from using a normal JavaScript eval()
>   in that it's executed within the global context (which is important
>   for loading external scripts dynamically).

From jQuery's source code `domManip` method:

```
// Evaluate executable scripts on first document insertion
for ( i = 0; i < hasScripts; i++ ) {
    node = scripts[ i ];
    if ( rscriptType.test( node.type || "" ) &&
        !jQuery._data( node, "globalEval" ) && jQuery.contains( doc, node ) ) {

        if ( node.src ) {
            // Hope ajax is available...
            jQuery._evalUrl( node.src );
        } else {
            jQuery.globalEval( ( node.text || node.textContent || node.innerHTML || "" ).replace( rcleanScript, "" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called from `append` method:

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {...});
}
```

To fix your issue, you could use javascript `appendChild` instead, e.g:

```
var head = $("#myframe")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'console.log("injected script using javascript appendChild:" ); console.log(document);';
head.appendChild(script);
```

### -=DEMO=-

Answer (score 0):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) Method

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#iFrameID").contents().find('head').append( script );
```